# How to connect to a remote computer and copy a file in its drive using C#.net or VB.Net programming

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I want to connect to a remote computer and copy a file in any location say C: drive using either C#.net or VB.net programming.

- I have got the remote computer name and citrix login credentials(username, pwd) with me.
- The remote machine's Remote Desktop Connection is disabled.
- There is no shared drive available for mapping.

What approach should I follow.

Comment: you can share a folder via the standard windows file sharing then google `how to download a file from network share in c#`

Comment: Are you copying to a shared folder on the remote computer? What have you tried so far?

Comment: You can use a network drive: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37717680/how-to-move-filesdlls-from-one-computer-another-computer-using-c-sharp/37717848#37717848

Comment: I have edited the question. Please see the modified question. The above approaches will not work there.

Answer (score 1):

Provided that the account running your application has sufficient user rights, you could try to use UNC paths to access the remote machine. Example:

```
\\machinename\c$\temp
\\machinename\d$\myApplication\Folder
```

You use these like normal paths in your C# application.

To switch to another user temporarily for the process of copying your files, you might want to try [impersonation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125341/how-do-you-do-impersonation-in-net).